# Extract frames from uncompressed y4m video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I am trying to get small sequences (64 frames) out of a big uncompressed y4m video.

The inputs are known test sequences from Netflix that I've got from: https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/

Since the video is uncompressed using copy as codec should just work. 
This is what I tried:

```
./bin/ffmpeg -ss 2.0 -i Netflix_TunnelFlag_4096x2160_60fps_10bit_420.y4m -vframes 64 -codec copy -y /tmp/test.y4m
```

But I get this error:

```
[yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x35f3320] ERROR: Codec not supported.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
```

I am not sure what could go wrong in such simple operation, I thought that FFMpeg should just copy the 64 I-frames and put them in a new container.

I also tried to change the container and the only thing that worked was using a yuv container but I'd like to avoid that since that's not a container :)

Comment: Remove `-codec copy`.

Comment: Thank you! What does the copy operation do then that is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `-codec copy`, and just use the defaults for y4m (it's rawvideo to rawvideo anyway).

The error "`Codec not supported`" message could be improved to be more informative. The yuv4mpegpipe muxer, along with some other rawvideo related muxers, will by default use the "wrapped_avframe" pseudo-encoder which,  ["avoids a costly memcpy of every single video frame"](http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-December/185681.html) compared to using the old API. See [Deprecating AVPicture](https://blogs.gentoo.org/lu_zero/2015/10/15/deprecating-avpicture/) for more info.

## tl;dr: It's faster.

Comment: Thanks I had other issue and you saved me .